# vector<double> type error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on my undergraduate thesis in mechanical engineering and I'm having trouble plotting data. The project is to use computer vision to automatically generate a high-quality CAD model of a real-world object.

I want to pass processed data to GNUPLOT in order to quickly generate a graph. I'm using temporary files to pass the data back and forth. (Note: if you know of a cleaner way to do this then by all means point it out.)

Every time I attempt to compile the program, though, I get the following error:

```
/home/ryan/Code/FullyReversed/fullyreversed.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference 
to `QImage fr::Plotter::plot<double>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >,
unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from. It seems that the compiler is replacing my `vector<double>` with another, more complex structure

So, in short, **what is the matter with the way I'm passing the data to `Plotter::plot`?**

### In my program's main class:

```
void MainWindow::plotData()
{
    double i;
    vector<double> intensity;
    static QImage plot;

    for(i=-10;i<10;i+=.1){
        intensity.push_back(1/(i*i+1));
    }

    plot = Plotter::plot(intensity,800,600);
    showQ(plot);
}
```

### In the auxiliary `Plotter` class:

```
template <typename T>
QImage Plotter::plot(vector<T, allocator<T> > data, unsigned int width, unsigned int height){

    // for creating the filename
    char buffer[256];

    // the file we'll be writing to
    ofstream file;

    // loop counter
    unsigned int i;

    // time file generated
    time_t ftime = time(NULL);

    // generate the filename
    sprintf(buffer,"%d.dat",ftime);

    // open the file
    file.open(buffer);

    // write the data to the file
    for(i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        file << i << " " << data.at(i) << endl;
    }

    //generate the command
    sprintf(buffer,"gnuplot -e \"set terminal png size %d, %d;set output '%d.png';plot sin(x);\"",width,height,ftime);

    // call GNUPLOT
    system(buffer);

    // load the image
    sprintf(buffer,"%d.png",ftime);
    QImage out = QImage(buffer);

    return out;
}
```

Comment: [It's the same thing.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: I'm guessing the `plot` function you show is actually a part of the `Plotter` class? And it _is_ defined in the header file and not in a source file?

Comment: @chris I figured it was the same thing, but the compiler doesn't think it is. And unfortunately it's the compiler's opinion that counts. I tried changing `vector<T>` to `vector<T, allocator<T> >` but I got an identical error.

Comment: The problem seems to be connected to the place of template function implementation. Do you have it in a header file or the same source file where it is used? BTW, I wouldn't make that template function static.

Comment: @RyanMuller, The point is that `std::vector` has two template parameters, with the second being defaulted. If you give it one template argument, it still has two.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, it is defined in a header file. I realized reading your comment that there was a horrible mistake in my syntax... but I fixed it and still get the _exact same error._ I've updated the code in my question to reflect the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a symptom of defining a template function in a source file instead of a header file.

A template isn't an actual function, it's just the instructions for building a function. The whole code needs to be available at the point where you call it so that the compiler can generate the proper function for you. If it doesn't have it, it assumes one is defined somewhere else and leaves the linker to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the function to the header file and dissolved the Plotter class, and the code now works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking about a frequently answered problem: You defined your template in a translation unit where it is invisible to compiler when you actually instantiate the template. That is OK as long as you realize that you need to explicitly instantiate the template if its definition cannot be found by the compiler for implicit instantiation.

An explicit instantiation would look something like this:

```
template QImage Plotter::plot(vector<double> data, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
```